# Typeorm default value for Time range column

Tags: database, postgresql, typeorm

I have a timestamp with timezone range column in postgresql. I am using typeorm. How can I insert default current timestamp as starting range?

Eg:-

```
@column({ type: 'timeStamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
time: Date;
```

Similarly I need default current time for range, lower limit also,

```
@column(( type: 'tstzrange'})
range: string;
```

i.e., ==> default value I need in range is [**'2022-08-11 06:38:16.378'**]

where **'2022-08-11 06:38:16.378'** is current time stamp..